# Display current date when saving/editing span (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, time

I have a fairly simple task list using `angularjs` and I would like to save the time when each task was created and update that time if the task is edited.

I'm thinking I could use something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RyW9m/) to display the current time, but I'm not sure how to do it on save/edit.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TodoListController">
  <form ng-submit="addTodo()" name="form">
      <input type="text" ng-model="todoText" size="30" placeholder="Add New Entry" required id="textField" ng-model="myVar">
      <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save">
  </form>
  <ul class="unstyled">
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos | orderBy : $index:true">
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" ng-click="remove(todo)">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <span class="done-{{todo.done}}" ng-style="todo.customStyle" ng-hide="todo.editing" ng-click="updateVar($event)">{{todo.text}}</span>
      <input type="text" ng-show="todo.editing" ng-model="todo.text">
      <button type="submit" ng-hide="todo.editing" ng-click="change(todo); todo.editing === true">Edit</button>

      <button type="submit" ng-show="todo.editing" ng-click="save($index); todo.editing === false">Save</button>
      <button type="submit" ng-show="todo.editing" ng-click="cancel($index); todo.editing === false">Cancel</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);
app.controller('TodoListController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.todos = [];
  $scope.newField = [];
  $scope.customStyle = {};
  $scope.addTodo = function () {
    $scope.todos.push({text: $scope.todoText, done: false, editing: false});
    $scope.todoText = '';
  };
  $scope.remaining = function () {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function (todo) {
      count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
    });
    return count;
  };
  $scope.delete = function () {
    var oldTodos = $scope.todos;
    $scope.todos = [];
    angular.forEach(oldTodos, function (todo) {
      if (!todo.done) $scope.todos.push(todo);
    });
  };
  $scope.remove = function () {
    $scope.todos.splice(this.$index, 1);
  };
  $scope.change = function (field) {
    var todoIndex = $scope.todos.indexOf(field);
    $scope.newField[todoIndex] = angular.copy(field);
    $scope.todos[todoIndex].editing = true;
  };  
  $scope.save = function (index) {
    $scope.todos[index].editing = false;
  };
  $scope.cancel = function (index) {
    $scope.todos[index] = $scope.newField[index];
  };
  $scope.updateVar = function (event) {
    $scope.myVar = angular.element(event.target).text();
  };
  $scope.editKeyword = function (name, index) {
    $scope.mode[index] = 'edit';
    console.log(name);
  };
}]);
```

Comment: So what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @Jax the problem is putting my idea together with my existing code. I'm unsure how to do it

Comment: @RicardoPimenta did you manage to find your solution. does my solution helped you or answer your question in any sense? I upvoted this question too.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `todoDate` attribute in the todo model like

```
$scope.todos.push({text: $scope.todoText, done: false, editing: false, todoDate: new Date()});
```

and update it when the user updates the todo object ie `save()`

```
$scope.save = function (index) {
    $scope.todos[index].editing = false;
    $scope.todos[index].todoDate = new Date();
};
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you call **save** function to add new todos simply add the **createdOn** field.

```
$scope.save = function (index) {
    $scope.todos[index].editing = false;
    $scope.todos[index].createdOn = new Date().getTime();
};
```

Now when user edits the todo and **change** function is called, do as below

```
$scope.change = function (field) {
    var todoIndex = $scope.todos.indexOf(field);
    $scope.newField[todoIndex] = angular.copy(field);
    $scope.todos[todoIndex].editing = true;
    $scope.todos[todoIndex].LastModifyOn = new Date().getTime();
  };
```

Now if this updated todo is again edited by the user we need to simply call **change** function and it will update the **LastModifyOn** filed.

So by doing this, we can keep both data like when was the todo created and when was it last gets updated.

Comment: The problem with this is that all tasks get the same exact hour of the first created, even after edition

Comment: After the edit, the LastModifyOn will get change for particular todo and the createdOn will not get changed.

Answer (score -1):

```
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);
app.controller('TodoListController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.todos = [];
  $scope.newField = [];
  $scope.customStyle = {};
  $scope.addTodo = function () {
    $scope.todos.push({text: $scope.todoText, done: false, editing: false, created: new Date()});
    $scope.todoText = '';
  };
  $scope.remaining = function () {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function (todo) {
      count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
    });
    return count;
  };
  $scope.delete = function () {
    var oldTodos = $scope.todos;
    $scope.todos = [];
    angular.forEach(oldTodos, function (todo) {
      if (!todo.done) $scope.todos.push(todo);
    });
  };
  $scope.remove = function () {
    $scope.todos.splice(this.$index, 1);
  };
  $scope.change = function (field) {
    var todoIndex = $scope.todos.indexOf(field);
    $scope.newField[todoIndex] = angular.copy(field);
    $scope.todos[todoIndex].editing = true;
    $scope.todos[todoIndex].created = new Date();
  };  
  $scope.save = function (index) {
    $scope.todos[index].editing = false;
    $scope.todos[index].created = new Date();
  };
  $scope.cancel = function (index) {
    $scope.todos[index] = $scope.newField[index];
  };
  $scope.updateVar = function (event) {
    $scope.myVar = angular.element(event.target).text();
  };
  $scope.editKeyword = function (name, index) {
    $scope.mode[index] = 'edit';
    console.log(name);
  };
}]);
```